# Executing multiple Oracle 11g functions from SQL Server

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g, ssis, sql-server-2012

This is my first time trying to execute function within Oracle 11g package from SQL Server. I begin with information that both databases sit on different servers.

Here goes. There are three functions to be executed that should return values from each function. I managed to run one function using SSIS returning value by way of debugging the SQL Execute Task.

Below is the SQL statement I wrote;

```
SELECT <Database_name>.<Package_name>.<Function_name>(?, ?, ?) FROM dual
```

I also specified 3 parameters for input.

Help me out to execute 2 more functions together. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So if you got it working for one function, why won't it work for function 2 and 3?

Comment: I don't know the correct syntax to join those other 2 functions. In fact I tried several combinations but no one is correct because debugging does not show any result from those two additional functions added.

Comment: I would think adding two more execute sql tasks to cover the other two functions would solve the problem. Am I missing some detail?

Comment: All those values coming out from each functions need to be written to SQL database as record. I'm not sure if this information is a requirement to have all functions to be within single Execute SQL Task. I'm new with regards to SSIS. Can it have multiple SQL Task in a single solution?